# How to make a circle and put text in the middle using CSS

Tags: html, css

Here is my fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjvggfwb/2/) And here is the code

```css
.optionalphabetnumber {
 background-color:#ff3333;
 color:white;
 width:20px;
 height: 20px; 
 text-align:center; 
  border-radius:50%;
}
button {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #777;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 66px;
    min-width: 320px;
    width: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;

}
```

```html
<button><span class="optionalphabetnumber">A &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>Superman</button>
```

I want to put "A" in a circle. But `border-radius:50%` is not making a perfect circle. And how do I put the text(just "A") in center?

Comment: Your `span` needs to be a rectangle for `border-radius: 50%;` to create a circle instead of an ellipse. That won't happen if the element is an inline element like a `span`. Change the display to a block level so dimensional properties like `height` and `width` will properly be applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you.

I have added `display: inline-block;margin-right: 5px;float: left;` to your `.optionalphabetnumber`, because `.optionalphabetnumber` is a `<span>` and it's default display attribute is `inline`. So it will not be aligned properly with other components neither we can style it properly. So by applying `display: inline-block;` we are overwriting its default attribute.

```css
.optionalphabetnumber {
  background-color: #ff3333;
  color: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  float: left;
}

button {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #777;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 66px;
  min-width: 320px;
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<button><span class="optionalphabetnumber">A</span>Superman</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set display to `inline-block`, and, optionally, give the circle some padding...

```css
.optionalphabetnumber {
  background-color: #ff3333;
  color: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

button {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #777;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 66px;
  min-width: 320px;
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<button>
<span class="optionalphabetnumber">A</span>Superman</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `display:inline-block;` to `.optionalphabetnumber`
The `<span>` is an `inline` element, height applied to inlines do not work like they do on a `block` or `inline-block`.

```css
.optionalphabetnumber {
 background-color:#ff3333;
 color:white;
 width:20px;
 height: 20px; 
 text-align:center; 
  border-radius:50%;
  display:inline-block;
}
button {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #777;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 66px;
    min-width: 320px;
    width: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;

}
```

```html
<button><span class="optionalphabetnumber">A &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>Superman</button>
```